# Use composer vendor from another Project

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm having problems importing classes declared in the namespace of another folder outside my project. So, this is the simplified DIR structure:

```
.
├── lib
│   ├── composer.json
│   ├── composer.lock
│   ├── Atrium
│   │   ├── Class1.php 
│   │   └── Class2.php 
│   └── vendor
└── Project
    ├── query.php
    ├── pipeline
    └── run.sh
```

What I'm trying to do is that the script `./Project/query.php` uses the `./lib/Atrium` classes (with namespace `Atrium` inside each class). For that purpose I declared the `lib/composer.json` as follows:

```
{
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Atrium\\": "./Atrium"
      }
    }
}
```

And run `composer dump-autoload` accorddingly.

**However when I `require` the `autoload` inside `./Project/query.php`, I end up with a `Undefined namespace` error for `Class1` and `Class2`.** *¿What am I doing wrong?*

This is the heading of the `query.php` script:

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/autoload.php';

use Atrium\Class1;
use Atrium\Class2;
```

`Atrium/Class1.php` has this heading (same for Class2):

```php
<?php

namespace Atrium;

use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;

class Class1 {
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the `require` actually work? `__DIR__` contains no trailing slash, so it might be that you're not actually including the autoloader file. Try `require __DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/autoload.php';`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast comment, I tried but no effect